# Who has a crown

Tags: riddle, rhyme

Who has a crown but is no king

Proclaimed his vows but has no ring

Tends a garden; rarely eats

Often sings but seldom speaks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It might possibly (though I'm not wholly convinced) be some sort of

> monk.

Who has a crown but is no king

> "Apart from this general clerical tonsure, some Western Rite monastic orders, for example Carthusians and Trappists, employed a very full version of tonsure, shaving the head entirely bald and keeping only a narrow ring of short hair, sometimes called "the monastic **crown**" (see "Roman tonsure", above), from the time of entrance into the monastic novitiate for all monks, whether destined for service as priests or brothers." (Wikipedia article on "Tonsure"; emphasis mine.)

Proclaimed his vows but has no ring

> Monastic rather than matrimonial vows. Pay no attention to the phrase "ring of short hair" in the material quoted above :-).

Tends a garden; rarely eats

> Monasteries usually have gardens. Various forms of self-denial are not uncommon in monastic orders, but I confess that "rarely eats" seems like a weak point.

Often sings but seldom speaks

> Monasteries have a lot of religious services, at some of which there will be singing. Some monastic orders (most famously the Trappists) refrain almost entirely from speaking; I think most are rather less chatty than the rest of us. I think, though, that for this one to work we need to take "often" and "seldom" as relative to how often most people sing (rarely) and speak (frequently).

Comment: Got it! Nicely done. Agree with the weak point -- I considered that an acceptable degree of stretch to preserve the beat & rhyme structure.

Answer (score 1):

Is it a

> A crowned conure(a bird)

As

> It has a crown like structure of feathers on its head, sings and can be seen in garden